# IntegrityError when Adding Social Application in Django: Null Value in Column "provider_id"

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-admin, google-oauth

## IntegrityError when Adding Social Application in Django: 'Null Value in Column "provider_id" violates non-null constraint'

[I am encountering an `IntegrityError`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdpkI.png) in my Django application when attempting to add a social application using Django Allauth. The error specifically points to a null value in the `provider_id` column, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve this.

The error occurs when I [try to add a new social application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Rqj.png) through the Django admin panel. Here's the detailed error message: ($ symbols are to block for privacy

```
IntegrityError at /admin/socialaccount/socialapp/add/
null value in column "provider_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (8, google, google, 888982092733-51qdar9ln6i5onjoli2blj9bb6$$$$$$$.apps.googleusercon..., GOCSPX-im5A3HBsy_5FFvJTKqz$$$$$$$, , null, null).
```

provider to Google, which is the only drop down option

all migrations have taken place in the code

## Google OAuth via django details

Authorised redirect URIs are linking to port urls.

Publishing status is in production.

## Resources being consulted.

Akamai DevRel. “Set up Google Sign-in for Faster Django Login Experience Feat. Tech with Tim.” YouTube, YouTube Video, 12 Dec. 2022, https://youtu.be/yO6PP0vEOMc?feature=shared&t=1386. Accessed 11 Nov. 2023.

- all steps have been followed to implement a google oauth with this tutorial, the issue arises around 23:06 when adding a social account.

---

“Django.” Django Project, 2023, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/. Accessed 11 Nov. 2023.

- django oauth appears to be correctly installed in settings.py as per this documentation

## Code Repository and plausible problem areas

https://github.com/lmcrean/Project-4 is the code repo -

problem areas could be

- [codestar/settings.py](https://github.com/lmcrean/Project-4/blob/main/codestar/settings.py) - but has been spellchecked rigorously. Perhaps INSTALLED_APPS and SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS (displayed below). Have tried two other versions of SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS, this doesn't seem to be the problem area.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cloudinary',
    'django_summernote',
    'crispy_forms',
    'blog',
    'users'
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "SCOPE": [
            "profile",
            "email"
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"access_type": "online"}
    }
}
```

- [users/models.py](https://github.com/lmcrean/Project-4/blob/main/users/models.py) since currently empty

## django admin available sites

when I try to [add social application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Rqj.png) I have 2 available sites, I wonder if these could be wrong now, but I can't see what could be wrong with them.

- http://127.0.0.1:8000
- https://8000-lmcrean-project4-avaw7dd1zq8.ws-eu106.gitpod.io/

Comment: Did you made a custom model/admin? If yes, share the code.

Comment: no custom model, no custom admin

Answer (score 0):

umm the provider is social provier? or u made table name like 'provider'?

if u use provider using 'google social login'

You can do this by setting the provider field on the social application object.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount, SocialApp

social_app = SocialApp.objects.create(
    provider='google',
    name='Google',
    client_id=YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    secret_key=YOUR_GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY,
)
```

and you can add it to your Django project by setting the SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS setting in your project's settings.py file. For example:

```
# settings.py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'PROVIDER': 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.GoogleProvider',
        'APP': {
            'client_id': YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            'secret_key': YOUR_GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY,
        }
    }
}
```

like this u have to

but if u means table name is 'provider' u have to share your code

Comment: https://github.com/lmcrean/Project-4 is the code repo

I've just tried running that command on python shell and got more or less same error message - NotNullViolation: null value in column "provider_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "SCOPE": [
            "profile",
            "email"
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"access_type": "online"}
    }
}  #here u have to write

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

**django-allauth was upgraded to from 0.44.0 to latest 0.59.0**

1. `pip uninstall django-allauth # uninstalls 0.44.0`
2. `pip install django-allauth # installs 0.59.0 by default`

the older version had been installed for a very specific reason to get some html working, I'm slightly surprised but it works with the latest now.

---

Then when it came to entering Social Applications there was the 'provider_id' label in the form, that was being described in the error message as null.

**Details were then entered on django admin as**

- Provider:Google (dropdown)
- Provider ID:google
- Name:Google SSO
- Client id: [your client id here]
- Secret key: [your secret key here]
- whatever site you're using added as site.

**And then Google sign in worked as expected**

made some migrations using the `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and was directed by the terminal to merge some old ones as well

---

I will document here for others that for creating Google signin, only remaining issue after the terminal error was resolving oauth Redirect error

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://8000-lmcrean-project4-avaw7dd1zq8.ws-eu106.gitpod.io/accounts/google/login/callback/
Related developer documentation
```

Django was trying to use

`http://8000-lmcrean-project4-avaw7dd1zq8.ws-eu106.gitpod.io/accounts/google/login/callback/`

And Oath URI was:

`https://8000-lmcrean-project4-avaw7dd1zq8.ws-eu106.gitpod.io/accounts/google/login/callback/`

So OAuth was changed to `http://` to match Django

Doing this also required moving Publishing status back from `Production` to `Testing` on OAuth consent screen.